# Python - try/except not working when variable assigned to sys.argv

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I have this section in my code:

```
# I/O files 
inp_arq = sys.argv[1]
out_arq = sys.argv[2]
pad_ref = "pad_ref03.fasta"
tes_mdl = "model_05_weights.best.hdf5"
```

and at the end:

```
try:
    results_df.to_csv(out_arq,index = False)
    print(f"File saved as: {out_arq}")
except IndexError:
    print("No output file created")
```

If no file is passed in as out_arq (sys.argv[2]) it should run the script and print "No output file created" at the end. But I'm getting the "IndexError: list index out of range."

But if I comment out the "out_arq = sys.argv[2]" line and change the code to:

```
try:
    results_df.to_csv(sys.argv[2],index = False)
    print(f"File saved as: {sys.argv[2]}")
except IndexError:
    print("No output file created")
```

It works and I got the message, but I'm not sure why. I'd like to have all my I/O file/vars at the begginig of the script, but with this one (out_arq) I can't.

How can I solve this? And why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace that is printed by the exception, you should see that the exception is raised on this line:

```
out_arq = sys.argv[2]
```

This is outside the `try` block, so the exception is not caught, and causes your program to terminate.

A solution is to check, before indexing the array, whether the element exists:

```
out_arq = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) >= 3 else None
```

Then use `if` instead of `try`:

```
if out_arq:
    results_df.to_csv(out_arq,index = False)
    print(f"File saved as: {out_arq}")
else:
    print("No output file created")
```

Comment: Alternatively, just move the statement that might get the error into the `try` block.

Comment: Sure @Barmar, but for a matter of code organization, I prefer Thomas answer. Thanks anyway.